# Can I give every structure entry a custom layout by using the same template?

Tags: entries, structure, slug

I want every structure entry to have a follow up page, http://thisismysite.com/handle/slug/followuppage.

So every slug, get a follow up page with different content but the same template. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you simply want to be able to find other content within the same section to link to? Like the siblings property of the current entry: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#siblings

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a [dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) for `/handle/<slug>/followuppage` and route the requests to your follow-up page template. From that template you’d have access to a variable called `slug` that you would then use to query for your structure entry.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('mystructure').slug(slug).first() %}

{% if not entry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```